# codility: EquiLeader Segmentation Fault problem in my code

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with this simple code. Propably the problem is with using the vector class:

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) {
    // write your code in C++14 (g++ 6.2.0)
    vector<int> left, right;
    int cnt=0,k,j;
    if (A.size()==1) return 0;
    if (A.size()==2 && A[0]==A[1]) return 1;
    if (A.size()==2 && A[0]!=A[1]) return 0;
    if (A.size()==3 && A[0]==A[1] && A[1]==A[2]) return 2;
    if (A.size()==3 && A[0]==A[1] && A[1]!=A[2]) return 0;
    for (size_t i=0; i<(A.size()-1); ++i)
    {
        left.assign( A.begin(), A.begin() + i );
        right.assign( A.begin() + i + 1, A.end());
        sort(left.begin(), right.end());
        sort(right.begin(), right.end());
        j=left.size()/2;
        k=right.size()/2;
        if (left[j]==right[k])
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

after execution it return :

```
stderr:
Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: `sort(left.begin(), right.end());` how do you think it'll work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`left[j]` is out-of-bounds if `i==0` because `left.size()` is `i`, so `0`.
Similar for `right[k]`.

Also the case `A.size() == 0` is not considered and will wrap around `A.size()-1`.

There is also a typo in `sort(left.begin(), right.end())`: `right.end()` should be `left.end()`.